# **WHY** would I use prefiltering in CRM 2011 report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I was told about pre-filtering when writing reports in CRM 2011 and it sounded like something I should add to my knowledge base so I Googled it and found:

[MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2009/03/06/microsoft-dynamics-crm-pre-filtering-tips.aspx)

[PowerObjects](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2012/05/31/microsoft-dynamics-crm-pre-filtering-for-crm-reporting/)

and a whole bunch more. These gave me a good understanding of the how for both automatic and explicit. The one thing I missed though was why. I mean in general the articles said things like context specific or reduce the size of the query but I failed to translate that into the nuts and bolts business case example. For example one of the articles stated that it will greatly enhance your reports but what does that mean to the person in sales running the report.

In other words I could easily add CRMAF_ to my queries but how it makes sales reports better I couldn't explain. Note I used better as that is the word the author of one article used so I took that to mean extra capability not better performance...?

So a quick business case understanding would be great.

Thank You

JB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy to make an example.

You need to create a simple report to display a list of accounts created starting from a selected date.

You just do a SQL Query as

```sql
SELECT * FROM FilteredAccount WHERE createdon => @selected_date
```

You publish your report and everyone is happy.

One month later there is a  new requirement and you need change the report because is necessary to filter also by country (or city, or a custom field)

Would you prefer to edit the report, adding parameters (and change the queries too) or enable pre-filtering and allow the user to apply some filters (based on fields that maybe will be added in the future) before your report runs?

Comment: OK...so pre-filtering pops a dialog to the sales person and they can choose from possible filtering options THUS making the report more powerful.

Comment: exactly, they can create a subset of the data passed to the report and for your queries this process is totally transparent